# How to better handle android live data errors in the subscribers

Tags: android, android-livedata

A simple code like this in your activity:

```
    viewModel.showLoggedInMenu.observe(this, Observer {
        nav_view.setMenu(R.menu.logged_in_menu)
    })
```

Where

```
    val showLoggedInMenu: LiveData<Unit>
```

Will freeze my app if nav_view is null,

I am looking for a consistent way to handle error situations for all my observers, the error should be surfaced somehow and the app should not freeze.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague when you mean "this types of issues", but to answer the immediate question, would you not just perform a null check?

```
nav_view?.let {
    it.setMenu(R.menu.logged_in_menu)
}
```

Comment: Even more concisely: `nav_view?.setMenu(R.menu.logged_in_menu)`

Comment: Edited, I am looking for a generic way to handle unforeseen exceptions in the observers.